# Share external USB HDD between PC and TV

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, tv

I bought an external hard drive which I would like to use for media storage. I managed to connect the HDD to the USB port of my wireless router and to use it as a network drive. So I can save movies on the external hard drive from my computer wirelessly.

Now I want to watch the movies on my TV. It works if I unplug the external hard drive from the router and connect it to the USB port of my TV. However I always have to do that manually.

I then tried to use a USB Hub but it did't work. It there any possibility that I use the HDD with the router and the TV at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you please tell us the brand of your router and your TV? This are important informations to help you. Please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Precisely, does you TV have network capabilities? If so, it should be easy to access a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

Very few TVs have it. In facts, they generally have few known codecs.
I advise you to steer you towards a multimedia box Android TV or Apple TV if you have the financial ability to get one.
Otherwise, lowcost solutions (I use one) like Raspberry PI + an embedded Raspbmc OS will allow you to recover all the desired content from your network share.
It's very powerfull and easy to use.